# How to Resync the Slave database automatically from Master database using a Windows Service?

Tags: mysql, database, windows-services, master-slave, mysqlbinlog

I am writing a Windows Service program to sync a local Slave database from the Master database continuously. I have a master database called `nsbm_syncdb`. If I want to Sync the slave database, I have to write the following query.

```
CHANGE MASTER TO
MASTER_HOST='192.168.1.1',
MASTER_USER='nsbm_root',
MASTER_PASSWORD='1234',
MASTER_LOG_FILE='mysql-bin.0000xx',
MASTER_LOG_POS=234;
```

For the above code, I should take the values of `MASTER_LOG_FILE` and `MASTER_LOG_POS` from the Master database by entering the query `"SHOW MASTER STATUS"`.

How can I retrieve the log position and log file name from the Master database using a MySql query?

I went through the internet but could not find a query yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `mysqldump` program (shipped with MySQL) with the [--master-data=2](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_master-data) option.

This will write the complete `CHANGE MASTER ...` command to the output.

Answer (score 0):

We  can write a C# code within the windows service program to access the values of the `SHOW MASTER STATUS` table.
Its not an existing table. So We have to create a `DataTable` and fill the details of the `SHOW MASTER STATUS` into that.

```
string master_log_file = null;
long master_log_pos = 0;

        using (MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(conStrM))
        {
            using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SHOW MASTER STATUS", con))
            {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                using (MySqlDataAdapter sda = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd))
                {
                    if (sda != null)
                    {
                        using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
                        {
                            sda.Fill(dt);
                            foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
                            {
                                master_log_file = row["File"].ToString();
                                master_log_pos = Convert.ToInt64(row["Position"]);
                            }
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
        }
```

from the above code we can get the `master_log_file` and the `master_log_pos`.